pyenv fails to install tkinter with python3.11+ on MacOS
So I ran into this issue about a year ago, but the app I was writing didn't depend on anything in 3.11 or higher specifically so I was okay just running on 3.10.14. Unfortunately, Apple decided to release MacOS15 Sequoia and now 3.10 tkinter just refuses to load some tk widgets on my app so I'm now forced to refactor everything for a newer version of python. This is where I run into the issue with pyenv is failing to install tkinter into any version of python later than 3.10. The steps I'm following to get tk are the following:
pyenv uninstall <all versions im not using>
brew uninstall python-tk@<all versions im not using>
brew uninstall tcl-tk  # just making sure its cleaned up
brew install python-tk@3.12  # for example, this also installs the relevant version tcl-tk afaik
pyenv install 3.12

and then I get this output for the last install command:
% pyenv install 3.12
python-build: use openssl@3 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.12.7.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.12.7/Python-3.12.7.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.12.7...
python-build: use tcl-tk from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/$USER/.pyenv/versions/3.12.7/lib/python3.12/tkinter/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
WARNING: The Python tkinter extension was not compiled and GUI subsystem has been detected. Missing the Tk toolkit?
Installed Python-3.12.7 to /Users/$USER/.pyenv/versions/3.12.7

This happens for 3.11, 3.12 and 3.13 with the exact same error message
I am pretty sure that I have setup all my pathing and env variables correct although this should not required any more for tkinter per Unable to install tkinter with pyenv Pythons on MacOS:
% echo $LDFLAGS
-L/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib
% echo $CPPFLAGS 
-I/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/include
% echo $PATH
/Users/$USER/.pyenv/shims:/Users/$USER/.pyenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/$USER/.toolbox/bin:/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/bin

I've also already attempted this fix: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/3041 but it hasn't resolved my issue nor any of the related pages referenced in there. I'm at a loss...
NOTE: username in all outputs was manually changed to $USER on this post for security purposes
EDIT: I get the same error if do:
brew install tcl-tk
pyenv install <version>

instead of python-tk@version
